# Environmentobject keep track of arrays variables

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm pretty new to xCode so this could have an obvious answer.
I've just learned about environment objects and created the following one:

```
import SwiftUI

class Data: ObservableObject {
    @Published var types = [Type]()
    @Published var customers = [Customer]()
    @Published var templates = [SubscriptionTemplate]()
    @Published var subscriptions = [Subscription]()
    @Published var giftCodes = [Giftcode]()
}
```

As you can see the object contains an array of objects. One of these is a customer array. The customer object looks like this:

```
import SwiftUI

class Customer: Identifiable, Codable{
    var id: Int
    var firstname: String
    var lastname: String
    var address: String
    var plz: Int
    var place: String
    var credit: Int
    
    init(id: Int, firstname: String, lastname: String, address: String, plz: Int, place: String, credit: Int) {
        self.id = id
        self.firstname = firstname
        self.lastname = lastname
        self.address = address
        self.plz = plz
        self.place = place
        self.credit = credit
    }
}

extension Customer: Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: Customer, rhs: Customer) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
}
```

In my project, I implemented an API call to update the customer. This works like a charm, but after updating, I also want to fetch the customer objects with the following method:

```
API().fetchCustomers { (customers) in
    self.data.customers = customers
}
```

After updating an object this doesn't work. The environment object doesn't update, but after creating a new object or fetching the data initial, it works.

What is the difference between the update and the create / fetch?

Comment: Could it be because the variables of the customer aren't declared with @Published? If yes how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make `Customer` a value type (ie. `struct`):

```
struct Customer: Identifiable, Codable{
    var id: Int

   // ... other code
```

Comment: I tried this and it didn't change anything. Still doesn't get updated.

Comment: With the struct I saw that my array does get updated but when displaying in a foreach loop it still shows the old value. Seems weird to me because it's an environment object so when changed the data should update.

Comment: That seems a different problem and related to view itself, don't put everything in one topic.